# Add object to a array of array

Tags: knockout.js

I want to add ingredient to a product object.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: products">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    <li>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: ingredients">
            <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    var viewmodel = {
        products: ko.observableArray([])
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
</script>
```

If I do the code below, it works fine:

```
viewmodel.products.push({
    name:"product name",
    ingredients:[{name:"ingredient 1"},{name:"ingredient 2"}]
})
```

But now I need to access the last product added and add an ingredient.. would be something like that:

```
viewmodel.products[0].ingredients.push({name:"ingredient 3"})
```

But when I do that, the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'ingredient' of undefined' throws.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to demonstrate your issue please?

Comment: @llya Sorry, groups was to be products. I just fix it in description.

Comment: @WickyNilliams Dont know why, but I cant insert HTML code in fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a fiddle for you. It works!

To access `products` you must wrote `products()[0]`, but not `products[0]`, because `()` means `get value`

this fiddle is in new knockout style

http://jsfiddle.net/hBsFM/3/

and this fiddle in the style that you use

http://jsfiddle.net/zjF6c/